# Double elements in list using prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

How can I double even numbers in a list in Prolog?
For example:

> X=[1,2,3,5,4]

The result should be:

> X=[1,2,2,3,5,4,4]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even check can probably be done better, but it kinda works.

```
even(N) :- 
    N mod 2 =:= 0.    

doubleeven([],[]).
doubleeven([H|T], [H,H|Z]) :-
    even(H),
    !,
    doubleeven(T,Z).
doubleeven([H|T], [H|Z]) :-
    doubleeven(T,Z).
```

Comment: Thank you! Lists in Prolog are very strange.

Comment: @Vidi, what's so strange? A list is a head and a tail (`[H|T]`), where the tail is also a list. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: `doubleeven([2],[2]).` succeeds, but it should fail.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915),
first define the
[reified test predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915) `eveninteger_t/2`:

```
eveninteger_t(I, T) :- 
   iwhen(nonvar(I), ( 0 is I mod 2 -> T = true ; T = false )).

oddinteger_t(I, T) :-   % defined for the sake of completeness
   iwhen(nonvar(I), ( 1 is I mod 2 -> T = true ; T = false )).
```

Then, in combination with [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) define `integers_evendups/2` like so:

```
integers_evendups([], []).
integers_evendups([X|Xs], [X|Zs1]) :-
   if_(evenintegers_t(X), Zs1 = [X|Zs0], Zs1 = Zs0),
   integers_evendups(Xs, Zs0).
```

Here's the query you gave in your question:

```
?- Xs = [1,2,3,5,4], integers_evendups(Xs,Zs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3,5, 4 ],
Zs = [1,2,2,3,5,4,4].
```

#### Alternative #1

Based on [`if_//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/4609915), define [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) `evenintegerdups//1`:

```
evenintegerdups([]) --> 
   [].
evenintegerdups([X|Xs]) -->
   if_(eveninteger_t(X), [X,X], [X]),
   evenintegerdups(Xs).
```

#### Alternative #2

Using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) and [lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), the code gets even shorter:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

evenintegerdups(Xs) -->
   foldl(\X^if_(eveninteger_t(X),[X,X],[X]),Xs).
```

Comment: Unusual naming: `Zs` and `Zs0` are typically used for differences. Here, there is none. So `Zs0`, `Zs1` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @false. Is the naming better now?

Comment: No: Think of it that way: Is there a DCG that could expand like that?