# How to remove even numbers in List using Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to remove all even numbers in first list and save the rest to second list.
My first non-working approach was:

```
remove_even([],[]).
remove_even([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):- 
    H1 mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove_even(T1,_).
remove_even([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    remove_even(T1,T2).
```

Sample query, run with SWI-Prolog 7.1.37:

```
?- remove_even([1,2,3,4],NewList).
NewList = [_G252, _G255|_G256].     % BAD! expected: NewList = [1,3]
```

What's wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**: next try, it is not working because `remove_even` once checked if it's valid even, then returned false and went to another rule, where recursion took place...

```
remove_even([],[]).
remove_even([El|T],[T]):- El mod 2 =:= 0.
remove_even([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    remove_even(T1,T1).
```

**UPDATE2:** have got lost in logic:

```
remove_even([],[]).
remove_even([El|T],T):-El mod 2 =:= 0. % removing the head if head is even
remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]) :-         % case where head is odd
    H mod 2 =\= 0,                     % rules that ensure head is odd
    remove_even(T1, T1). 

    % just copying T1 from source list to destination, 
    % will look up T1 values in next recursive iteration when it becomes a H.
```

**UPDATE3:** followed recommendations but it still doesn't work.

```
remove_even([],[]).
remove_even([El|T], NewT)   :- El mod 2 =:= 0, remove_even(T, NewT).
remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- H  mod 2 =\= 0, remove_even(T1, T1).
```

**UPDATE4:** no singleton error

```
remove_even([],[]).
remove_even([El|T], NewT)  :- El mod 2 =:= 0, remove_even(T, NewT).
remove_even([El|T1], NewT) :- El mod 2 =\= 0, remove_even(T1,[NewT|T1]).
```

**UPDATE5:** got it working, but have almost no idea how (some magic ;) maybe ) . `gtrace` is good but would be useful to have Prolog to draw some kind of decision tree or some easily understandable graphical representation of it's steps.

```
remove_even([],[]).
remove_even([El|T], NewT)   :- El mod 2 =:= 0, remove_even(T, NewT).
remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- H  mod 2 =\= 0, remove_even(T1, T2).
```

How to interpret logically last clause taking into account recursion calls?
My try: `[H|T2]` is a list with even elements removed from `[H|T1]` **IFF** Heads of both Lists is odd AND Tail `T2` of destination list is a Tail `T1` with all even elements removed. Correct?

Comment: In your second clause, `H2` and `T2` are singleton meaning you haven't indicated in the rule where they come from. In the third clause, both `H1` and `H2` are singleton, so you haven't completed the logic in your rule in that case either.

Comment: In your update, your second clause, `T` (a tail) is already a list. So you don't want `[T]` but just `T`. In your third clause, `H1` and `H2` are still singleton and now so is `T2`.

Comment: In your second update, your second clause will allow `T` to have even elements. In other words, it says that *a list `[E1|T]` with even elements removed is `T` if `E1` is even.* In other words, it removes the first element if it's even and then declares victory. It doesn't indicate what to do with `T` other than include it in the result. I think your third clause looks good.

Comment: You didn't quite follow all recommendations. ;) It doesn't work because your 3rd clause is wrong. HINT1: `T2` is a singleton. HINT2: re-read my answer regarding the updated third clause. :)

Comment: I don't get it. I need some variable to hold values for my future List. It's instantiated during runtime I think. I can get rid of singleton error by changing the last sentence to `[NewT|T1]`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Think through your new 3rd rule and determine if it sounds logical. You removed the singleton by making the clause less logical and deviated further from my answer. I said for the third rule: *...and define how T1 and T2 are related*. Going back to a rule that says, `remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]) :-...`, if `H` is odd, how are `T1` and `T2` related to each other?

Comment: Why it's necessary to press `;` for Prolog to continue and return `false` (using last version of this program) ?

Comment: That's just how prolog works. If there's a choice point in the prolog logic when presenting a solution, you press `;` and it will seek other solutions. When it finds no more, it displays `false` or `no` (no more solutions). Regarding not knowing how your program works, it should be logical if you think about it the way I described in my answer. Your last clause, for example, says, `[H|T1]` with even elements removed is `[H|T2]` if `H` is odd, and if `T2` is the list you get when removing even elements from `T1`. Isn't that logical? :)

Comment: In your last interpretation of clause 3, you are saying, *...IFF heads of both lists is odd...* but that's not quite right. The clause uses `H` for both heads, so the heads are not only odd but *identical* (it's the same value), which is important since we want the second list to have the same values as the first list, just not the even ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you have singleton variable warnings is a clue that something isn't right. Your clause header implies you care about a particular variable, but the clause logic doesn't instantiate it or otherwise use it.

Analyzing the rules (clauses) you provided

```
remove_even([],[]).
```

Good rule. *An empty list with the even numbers removed is the empty list.*

```
remove_even([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):- 
    H1 mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove_even(T1,_).
```

This rule says, *`[H2|T2]` is the list `[H1|T1]` with even numbers removed if `H1` is even, and if I remove the evens from `T1` and discard them*. That doesn't sound right. It also doesn't say how you are to obtain `H2`. Note: you may not want to split the result list in this clause into head and tail if the logic doesn't dictate.

```
remove_even([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    remove_even(T1,T2).
```

This rule says that *`[H2|T2]` is `[H1|T1]` with even numbers removed if `T2` is `T1` with the even numbers removed*. That sounds partially correct, but the rule doesn't indicate how to handle `H1` and `H2`.

**UPDATE**: in your update, the new second clause:

```
remove_even([El|T],[T]):- El mod 2 =:= 0.
```

This is closer. One problem is that `T` is already a list, so you don't want `[T]` but just `T`. Then it becomes:

```
remove_even([E1|T], T) :- E1 mod 2 =:= 0.
```

Which says: *The list `[E1|T]` with even elements removed is the list `T` if `E1` is even*. This is a correct statement but isn't complete logic. It doesn't make any stipulation about `T`. What if the list `T` has even elements? See @Sergey's answer for a corrected version of this specific clause.

Your updated third clause has some new issues:

```
remove_even([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    remove_even(T1,T1).
```

There are three singleton variables. The rule says, *`[H1|T1]` with even elements removed yields `[H2|T2]` if `T1` is itself with even elements removed (i.e., `T1` has no even elements)*. That doesn't sound logical at all. So you need to rethink that rule. I assume you are intending the case where the head is odd (since clause 2 deals with an even head). In that case, you are just copying the head over to the result list. Your clause heading should then look like:

```
remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]) :-   % case where head is odd
     % put rules here that ensure head is odd, and define how T1 and T2 are related
```

So you would ultimately have 3 clauses: (1) removing the even elements from an empty list, (2) removing even elements from a list whose head is even, and (3) removing the even elements from a list whose head is odd. That all sounds complete. Just follow the logic.

**UPDATE4 Response:**

The new 3rd clause eliminates a singleton by introducing some issues:

```
remove_even([El|T1], NewT):-         
    El mod 2 =\= 0,                     
    remove_even(T1, [NewT|T1]).
```

Reading through: *`[E1|T1]` with even elements removed is `NewT` if `E1` is odd and `[NewT|T1]` is a list with even elements removed from `T1`*. A BIG problem here is that you are using `NewT` (a list) as the head of another list `[NewT|T1]`, so it's now a list of lists, which will not match anything. See the prior hint for clause 3 above. In addition, there's no longer a part of the rule that says `E1` is part of `NewT`. If `E1` is odd, it should be part of the the other list when even elements are removed.

**UPDATE5 Response (why does it now work?):**

So the final working version looks like this:

```
remove_even([],[]).
```

As before: if you remove the even elements of an empty list, you get an empty list.

```
remove_even([El|T], NewT):- 
    El mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove_even(T, NewT).
```

`NewT` is the list `[E1|T]` with even elements removed if `E1` is even and `NewT` is `T` (the "tail list" of the original list) with the even elements removed from `T`. In other words, we dropped `E1` (an even element, head of the first list - we don't want it any more since it's even) and are left with `T`, the rest of the list which we want to "process" and find the list that's like `T` but with the even elements removed.

```
remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]):-         
    H mod 2 =\= 0,                     
    remove_even(T1, T2).
```

We've covered this one before, but for completeness: `[H|T1]` with even elements removed is `[H|T2]` if `H` is not even and `T1` with its even elements removed is `T2`. Your description of this clause reads, *[H|T2] is a list with even elements removed from [H|T1] IFF Heads of both Lists is odd AND Tail T2 of destination list is a Tail T1 with all even elements removed.* This isn't quite accurate. You're saying, "...IFF heads of both lists is odd...", whereas in the clause, we are saying the heads are **identical** and odd (it's the same number), not just both odd.

All of the cases are covered as I described further before in my answer. If you think about it logically, it makes sense. :)

Comment: (3) why do we look for odd number (also) in head of result list `remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]):-H mod 2 =\= 0, .......`  ?

Comment: @RCola think about it logically. If I just said `remove_even([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- % some logic showing how T1 and T2 are related` then this would allow `H` to be part of the odd list even if `H` were even. You obviously don't want that. Odd is the opposite of even and the 3rd rule is dealing with the case where the head is odd. Your second rule deals with the case where the head is even. You don't want the third rule to allow all cases of the head.

Answer (score 2):

If your Prolog system offers [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), then this answer is for you.
(If not, please read on, too!)

By using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) and the 
[reified predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915) [`zodd_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915), simply write:

```
?- tfilter(zodd_t,[1,2,3,4],Zs). % remove even integers = keep odd integers
Zs = [1,3].
```

As we only use **monotone** code here, we get sound answers for more general queries, too:

```
?- tfilter(zodd_t,[A,B,C],Zs).
Zs = [     ], A mod 2 #= 0, B mod 2 #= 0, C mod 2 #= 0 ;
Zs = [    C], A mod 2 #= 0, B mod 2 #= 0, C mod 2 #= 1 ;
Zs = [  B  ], A mod 2 #= 0, B mod 2 #= 1, C mod 2 #= 0 ;
Zs = [  B,C], A mod 2 #= 0, B mod 2 #= 1, C mod 2 #= 1 ;
Zs = [A    ], A mod 2 #= 1, B mod 2 #= 0, C mod 2 #= 0 ;
Zs = [A,  C], A mod 2 #= 1, B mod 2 #= 0, C mod 2 #= 1 ;
Zs = [A,B  ], A mod 2 #= 1, B mod 2 #= 1, C mod 2 #= 0 ;
Zs = [A,B,C], A mod 2 #= 1, B mod 2 #= 1, C mod 2 #= 1.
```

---

We can use above code even without [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), simply by using different [reified predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915):
[`eveninteger_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308758/4609915) → [`zeven_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915), and
[`oddinteger_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308758/4609915) → [`zodd_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915).

Sample query:

```
?- tfilter(oddinteger_t,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Xs).
Xs = [1,3,5,7].
```

---

#### Edit 2015-06-06

Let's try the following variation!

Instead of using `zodd_t/2` directly, rather use `zeven_t/2` and `not_t/3`:

```
truth_negated(true,false).
truth_negated(false,true).

not_t(Goal,Param,Truth1) :-       % meta-predicate, negate truth value
   call(Goal,Param,Truth0),
   truth_negated(Truth0,Truth1).
```

Let's see it if works with a head-to-head comparison:

```
?- tfilter(      zodd_t  ,[1,2,3,4],Zs).
Zs = [1,3].

?- tfilter(not_t(zeven_t),[1,2,3,4],Zs).
Zs = [1,3].
```

Comment: `_t` stands for truthvalue. `t` and `f` are not common values in Prolog they are known to Scheme as `#t`. Rather `true` and `false`.  the `_t` corresponds to the `t` as prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at one of your clauses:

```
remove_even([El|T],[T]) :- El mod 2 =:= 0.
```

First, in the notation [El|T] El is a single item, and T is a list. Then [T] will be list inside a list, which probably is not what you want. It should be just "remove_even([El|T],T)".

Next, your variant of the rule just copies T into the answer, not removing any even numbers from the tail. Only the first number (if it's even) will be removed. remove_even should be applied to the T also.

In the end we should have something like this:

```
remove_even([El|T], NewT) :- 
    El mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove_even(T, NewT).
```

Comment: Your last suggestion of `remove_even` rule is not working on it's own. `False` is returned.

Comment: It's only one of the clauses. The clause for the empty list and a clause when the first element is not even must be added.

Comment: @RCola, Sergey has given you what the second clause should look like. You still need your first clause, and a reworked third clause per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

an handy library builtin is [exclude](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3)

```
1 ?- [user].
|: even(N) :- N mod 2 =:= 0.
% user://1 compiled 0.02 sec, 2 clauses
true.

2 ?- exclude(even, [1,2,3,4], L).
L = [1, 3].
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean maybe I read this wrong but don't you think you all way overthought this problem? So taking out all even elements in the first list and storing them in the second list I was able to do that just by skipping over every even element, like so:

```
remove_evens([], Ys).
remove_evens([X], [X|Ys]).
remove_evens([X,_|Xs], [X|Ys]):-
  remove_evens(Xs, Ys), !.
```

which in turn would give this result:

```
| ?- remove_evens([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], List2).
List2 = [1,3,5,7|_]
```

Comment: This cut plus incorrect first and second clause leads to may bizarre errors, like: `remove_evens([a,_,b,_,c],[a,b,c]).` correctly succeeds, but `remove_evens([],[a,b,c]).` succeeds, too.